# IP Address not populating in eth0 in ifconfig

Tags: networking, centos

One of my servers at work does not connect back to us (so I can't SSH into it). I asked the person on the site to do numerous things:

`sudo /sbin/service network restart`

It comes up with this: [image]

I had him check the conf file to make sure the IP address is correctly in there using:

`cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

And it comes up as (has correct IP):

```
     ip: 192.168.x.x
submask: 255.255.255.0
     dg: 192.168.x.x
```

Everytime he runs `/sbin/ifconfig -a | less`, this is what comes up:

[image]

Is there any kind of hardware test I can run on the machine CentOS/SL that can check for hardware failures on the NIC? If not that, what other things can I check that may help isolate where the trouble is?

Comment: If you're saying that the system is supposedly configured with a static IP, then it's not a hardware issue. The first screen shows it trying to use DHCP to acquire an address. The system is misconfigured, it's not using the static address.

Comment: Pasting the whole of `ifcfg-eth0` would be useful, plus if you could run `dmesg | grep eth`, and this should confirm the assigned interfaces.

Comment: @Patrick. Good catch! How did you conclude this. I looked at the first screen shot but could not see anything that can point towards a misconfiguration. You mind providing more details in an answer? :)

Comment: @ryekayo `Determining IP information for eth0...` means it's trying to use DHCP. Static configuration won't show that. I think you providing an answer to your own question with exactly what was wrong would be more appropriate. No harm in answering your own question :-)

Comment: Please post code blocks with terminal output instead of images of terminal output. The result is more readable, more compatible with browsers, and less bandwidth-heavy.

Comment: @HalosGhost I dont have direct access to the machine which is why I had to use screenshots. My first sentence says I cannot SSH into the machine in the first place, Im not sure why you would down-vote my question when I mentioned that to begin with..

Comment: I react poorly to images of terminal output. It is not difficult to curl command output to a pasteclient like ix or sprunge. And it makes everyone's lives simpler.

Comment: @HalosGhost, I had enough trouble trying to instruct the IT on what to do since they mainly deal with Windows machines. The best I could do was tell them to submit screenshots and give them step-by-step instructions on re-configuring the config file in network-scripts. Anything more than that, and I'm sure the IT at the site I was troubleshooting with would more than likely could have run into even more trouble than what it is worth trying to have them send me a code block for UL overflow, so me and my colleagues had to make do with screen shots which helped us solve the problem anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first picture provided `Determining IP information for eth0`. This generally means it is misconfigured to static. I concurred this when I had the on-site provide a screenshot of the output of `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` which shows `BOOTPROTO` is in fact configured to dhcp. Right now, I am having the on-site change the field to static and restart the machine so that the IP address can be correctly set. Thanks for the help.